# CalendarPickerView not able to initialize inside of Firebase get call

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar that displays which days free and which days are not free. I have dates stored in firebase and am trying to load them into the calendar however I am getting issues. I am able to able to grab the dates however the when I try to load the calendar, I get an error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must have at least one month to display.  Did you forget to call init()?
```

If I try to load it outside of the get call, the arraylist for `bookReservationDateGroupArrayList` returns empty and no dates are shown as "unavailable".

here is my code:

```
    CalendarPickerView bookProfileCalendar;

    ArrayList<String> bookReservationDateGroup;
    ArrayList<String> bookReservationDateGroupString = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Date> bookReservationDateGroupArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**OnCreate**

```
createCalendar();
```

**createCalendar function**

```
private void createCalendar() {

        loadBookReservationDates();

        final Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastYear.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);


        final Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);


        bookProfileCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);

        final ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

        getIncomingIntent();

        bookPendingRequests = firestoreDB.collectionGroup("bookPendingRequests")
                    .whereEqualTo("bookRequestParentId", bookFirebaseIdString)
                    .whereEqualTo("bookReservationStatus", "Accepted");

        bookPendingRequests.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {


                // able to get book reservation info through here below
                for (int i = 0; i < task.getResult().size(); i++) {
                    QuerySnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    bookReservationDateGroup = (ArrayList<String>) document.getDocuments().get(i).get("bookReservationDates");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: dategroup: " + bookReservationDateGroup);

                    bookReservationDateGroupString.addAll(bookReservationDateGroup);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete inside for loop : " + bookReservationDateGroupString);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete outside for loop : " + bookReservationDateGroupString);


                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");


                    for (String individualDate: bookReservationDateGroupString) {

                        Date unformattedInputDate = dateFormatInput.parse(individualDate.trim());
                        String formattedOutputDateString = dateFormatOutput.format(unformattedInputDate);
                        Date formattedOutputDate = dateFormatOutput.parse(formattedOutputDateString);
                        Log.d(TAG, "createCalendar: formattedOutputDateString: " + formattedOutputDateString);

                        bookReservationDateGroupArrayList.add(formattedOutputDate);
                        Log.d(TAG, "createCalendar: arrayListHighlightedDates: " + bookReservationDateGroupArrayList);


                    }

                    bookProfileCalendar.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime(), new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, YYYY", Locale.getDefault())) //
                            .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)
                            .withHighlightedDates(bookReservationDateGroupArrayList);
                    Log.d(TAG, "createCalendar: hilighted dates at init: " + bookReservationDateGroupArrayList);

                    bookProfileCalendar.scrollToDate(new Date());

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure() returned: " + e);
            }
        });        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to stumble on the answer ironically.

I added this after the `OnFailureListener`

and it works somehow

```
bookProfileCalendar.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime(), new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, YYYY", Locale.getDefault()));
```

who woulda thunk it.